# ReduceByKey Function - Spark Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have got an RDD;

```
[(25995522, '2013-03-04 21:55:42.000000'),
 (25995522, '2013-03-15 03:51:30.000000'),
 (25995522, '2013-03-07 01:47:45.000000'),
 (52198733, '2013-03-17 20:54:41.000000'),
 (52198733, '2013-03-11 02:56:47.000000'),
 (52198733, '2013-03-13 10:00:04.000000'),
 (52198733, '2013-03-13 23:29:26.000000'),
 (52198733, '2013-03-04 21:44:58.000000'),
 (53967034, '2013-03-13 17:55:40.000000'),
 (53967034, '2013-03-14 04:03:55.000000')]
```

I would like to reduce them by the date where the date is the minimum. The output should be;

```
[(25995522, '2013-03-04 21:55:42.000000'),
 (52198733, '2013-03-04 21:44:58.000000'),
 (53967034, '2013-03-13 17:55:40.000000')]
```

How could I reduce them by their dates, instead of using ".reduceByKey(add)"? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you not want to use `reduceByKey`?  Seems like the perfect thing to do here.

Comment: I would like to use reduceByKey but I don't know which parameter I should put inside

Comment: What you need is a function that takes two dates and returns the smaller one.

Comment: How could I do that? I am at beginner stage so if you would help me I will be appreciated.

Comment: I refer you to the Javadoc for the [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class in core Java.

Comment: Excuse me but I couldn't understand. I need a parameter for  ".reduceByKey()" function. Why did you refer the LocalDateTime class for Java?

Comment: I am using Apache Spark by the way

Answer (score 0):

```
res = rdd.mapValues(lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: min(x, y))
```

Or:

`rdd.groupByKey` will not provide much better performance.